# Bootstrap alternative or easy HTML alignment library

Tags: html, css, asp.net, frontend

Is there any alternatives for bootstrap or any predefined CSS library to align and set up a HTML page pretty easily?

I'm doing my development with asp.net and bootstrap and now I got bored of it. So if there is a new library or CDN it would help me a lot.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to this to get started with asking question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I found https://bulma.io is a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of other free css frameworks with easy to understand grid layouts.

For example:

- http://foundation.zurb.com/
- http://960.gs/
- http://getbase.org/

But it totally depends on your usage case which to use (for example if you want to use sass, etc.).

Comment: Thank you Paul! I think it would help me.

Answer (score 0):

yes you have many libraries

- http://cardinalcss.com/
- http://getskeleton.com/
  etc

but remember the support ability is limited than Bootstrap. Also totally different keywords.

Comment: Thank you SakkaDotNet! I will look forward to your references.